# Send ajax request when textfield's OnBlur event is fired

Tags: ajax, jquery, textfield

Is is possible to use AJAX on an onblur event from a textfield. I'd like html (inside a div container) to change whenever I tab out of a textfield. I see a lot of questions/tutorials using AJAX with forms but not on the individual components such as textfield or checkbox.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it using plain JQuery. Assuming your form element has the ID of my_element:

```
$("#my_element").blur(function(){
  $.ajax({url: '/my/data', type: 'GET'})
  .done(function(response){
    $("#my_div").html(response);
  })
})
```